# Oracle SQL Developer Create new connection Error message: Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm trying to create a new connection in SQL Developer (following homework's instructions), as requested I have filled in the information, but it keep reporting error message when I tried Test and Status shows this error message:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password;
> logon denied

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nZID.png)

I searched and some people said should go to TNSNAMES.ORA file look for names and password, but I don't see my TNSNAMES.ORA file has these information
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tES4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53QEx.png)

Below is what the instruction asks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC9eo.png)

I have tried to just come up with the name at the beginning and getting the message, and also search names and password in the TNSNAMES.ORA file but find nothing, not sure how I can get the correct username and password here.
Please indicate the steps of how to find the correct username and password if you know, and it has to be tested and show status success.
Thank you

Comment: my friend helped me solved my issue by typing: "CREATE USER name IDENTIFIED BY password;" to create user, then: "GRANT CONNECT TO name;" to grant connection, then the user was successfully created in my 1st SYS connection, then I was able to create a new connection based on the name and password I just created

Answer (score 1):

This is a not a tnsnames.ora problem.

If you get ORA-1017 it means you *successfully* made contact with the database, ie, the database is open, it is responding to requests via the listener. Everything is working fine.

However, your username or password is incorrect which is why you cannot get onto the database.

One cause might be because you have chosen SYSDBA as the connection type - I suspect that GENUSER is a normal user not a SYSDBA, so change that.

Also, passwords are case sensitive so double check that as well.

Comment: I have changed role to default, and one important thing is I couldn't find the username and password, so what you see above, is just the username and password that I made up, as indicated in the question, the file TNSNAMES.ORA seems like suppose to provide username and password, but mine didn't see, so I don't even know what are the usernames and passwords I can use from the file. I need help with finding usernames and passwords as well.

Comment: Ah...well that is a tougher proposition :-) Since this db is running on localhost, its the PC you are currently using.  You should be able to fire up a command prompt and do: sqlplus / as sysdba.  That should let you in without a password and then you can create a user